# Stop Postback with Submit button When Warning Users They Are Leaving a Form with Unsaved Data

Tags: javascript, .net, forms, webforms

I created a form using C#.  To warn users about leaving the site before making changes, I added this JavaScript

```
var warnMessage = "You have entered new data on this page.  If you navigate away from this page without first saving your data, the changes will not be saved. To save your data, click the Cancel button, then save your data before leaving this page.";

var g_isPostBack = false;

function windowOnBeforeUnload() {
    if (g_isPostBack == true)
        return; // Let the page unload

    if (window.event)
        window.event.returnValue = warnMessage; // IE
    else
        return warnMessage; // FX
}

window.onbeforeunload = windowOnBeforeUnload;
```

When you leave the page, it works fine. The problem is it also fires even after you save the form data.

When you click the Submit button a postback occurs, which sets the variable g_isPostback to false.

Anyone have a way to prevent the postback with the submit button.

Comment: in the OnClick event of the Submit button (client side), set g_isPostBack to false

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, both of which make use of your form's `onSubmit` event.

**Option A:**

```
function formOnSubmit(e) {
    g_isPostBack = true;
```

}

**Option B:**

```
function formOnSubmit(e) {
    window.onbeforeunload = false;
}
```

I would recommend option A based on your existing code. Don't forget to bind your form's `onSubmit` to the `formOnSubmit()` function.